# What were Vegeta and Nappa's power levels in DBZ Season 1?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

I just finished watching the awesome fight between Goku and friends versus Vegeta and Nappa. Throughout the fight, the two evil saiyans constantly read the power levels of the "good" guys. However, not once do they mention their own powers.

Was this documented anywhere? Maybe the books?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Vegeta's power level is 18,000 as stated in the original manga. [Vol. 21, #249]**

**Nappa's power level is 4,000, as stated in Weekly Shōnen Jump. [Weekly Shōnen Jump, issue 31st, 1989]**

- Power levels are one of the most contested aspects of the Dragon Ball Manga. So much so, even when characters stopped having power levels published, fans would still try to create tables of comparison.
- Many Japanese fan magazines even join in the fun creating charts and graphs of different era Dragonball heroes. The Dragon Ball Wiki keeps a running tab of [**power levels**](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Power_Levels) and the different Dragon Ball Series.

[image]

Comment: Wow 18,000. That's crazy. I agree, power levels are interesting to compare.

Comment: If that's the case, why was Nappa so worried that it was OVER 9000!!!! ?

Comment: Note Nappa's power level. He was worried about himself since Goku was twice his level.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks by the way the over 9000 is a loss in translation, in the original he says a different number

Answer (score 3):

The original is "over 8,000". It was changed to "9,000" in the 'ocean dub'.

I am pretty sure this change was made to match Vegeta's mouth movements better.